# Userform data to populate specific tables on worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have been searching high and low and have come up with some results but not what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have two different userforms, one to create a Purchase Order, another to create a Change Order.  Depending on the userform that is selected, once data is entered and the command button is used, I need the data to populate either Table1 (for Purchase Orders from the POUserform) or Table2 (for Change Orders from the COUserform).  Both tables are on the same worksheet.  Is this even possible???

Below is the code I currently have - it always wants to populate the same Table no matter what userform I am running.

*Note that the code for Userform 1 and Userform 2 are exactly the same with the exception of "Table1" and "Table 2".*

```
Private Sub SendCOButton_Click()

Dim xSht As Worksheet
Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
Dim xFolder As String
Dim xYesorNo As Integer
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim xEmailObj As Object
Dim xUsedRng As Range

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Dim iRow As Long
  Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet, WS3 As Worksheet
  Set WS1 = Worksheets("Original Contracts")
  Set WS2 = Worksheets("Purchase Order Template")
  Set WS3 = Worksheets("Project Snapshot")

'find first empty row in database
iRow = WS1.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

LastRow = WS3.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(WS3.Range("A1:A5000", WS3.Cells(LastRow, 1)), 
Me.CONo.Value) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Duplicate Change Order Number!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If


'copy the data to the database
'use protect and unprotect lines,
'     with your password
'     if worksheet is protected

With WS1
End With

With WS2
  .Range("H1").Value = Me.CONo.Value
  .Range("B6").Value = Me.COTradeList.Value
  .Range("H6").Value = Me.COAttn.Value
  .Range("B7").Value = Me.COEmail.Value
  .Range("H7").Value = Me.COPhone.Value
  .Range("H16").Value = Me.COPrice1.Value
End With

With WS3
  rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = CONo.Value
  rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = COTradeList.Value
  rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = COItems.Value
  rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow, 4).Value = CODescription1.Value
  rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow, 5).Value = COPrice1.Value
  rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow, 6).Value = CODateIssued.Value
End With

Set xSht = Worksheets("Purchase Order Template")
Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

If xFileDlg.Show = True Then
   xFolder = xFileDlg.SelectedItems(1)
Else
   MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." & vbCrLf & 
   vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Must Specify 
   Destination Folder"
 Exit Sub
End If
xFolder = xFolder + "\" & Worksheets("Purchase Order 
Template").Range("B9").Value & " - PO No. " & Worksheets("Purchase Order 
Template").Range("G1").Value & " - " & Worksheets("Purchase Order 
Template").Range("B6").Value & ".pdf"

'Check if file already exist
If Len(Dir(xFolder)) > 0 Then
   xYesorNo = MsgBox(xFolder & " already exists." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do 
   you want to overwrite it?", _
                  vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")
On Error Resume Next
If xYesorNo = vbYes Then
    Kill xFolder
Else
    MsgBox "if you don't overwrite the existing PDF, I can't continue." _
                & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", 
vbCritical, "Exiting Macro"
    Exit Sub
End If
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Unable to delete existing file.  Please make sure the file is 
not open or write protected." _
                & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", 
vbCritical, "Unable to Delete File"
    Exit Sub
  End If
End If

Set xUsedRng = xSht.UsedRange
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xUsedRng.Cells) <> 0 Then
'Save as PDF file
xSht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=xFolder, 
Quality:=xlQualityStandard

'Create Outlook email
Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
Set xSht = Worksheets("Purchase Order Template")
With xEmailObj
    .Display
    .To = Worksheets("Purchase Order Template").Range("B7").Value
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Worksheets("Purchase Order Template").Range("E9").Value & " 
  - " & "PO# " & Worksheets("Purchase Order Template").Range("G1").Value & 
  " - " & Worksheets("Purchase Order Template").Range("B6").Value
    .Attachments.Add xFolder
    If DisplayEmail = False Then
        '.Send
        End If
    End With
 Else
  MsgBox "The active worksheet cannot be blank"
  Exit Sub
 End If

  Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: You create a `Range` called `rng` and (in this example code) refer it to `Table2` but thereafter you only ever use the range to locate it's `.Parent` sheet...?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking - if my coding is incorrect, please help me understand what I've done wrong.

Comment: *it always wants to populate the same Table no matter what userform* -  that's because although you're setting `rng` to the table, you then don't use `rng` for anything other than locating a sheet.

Answer (score 1):

We have NO idea on the layout of your sheets, but we can try to get a picture of what's happening using the code:

This section appears to be the part which (I assume) you change to refer to the appropriate table:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range
```

You then, later in the code, write to a sheet using:

```
With WS3
  rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = CONo.Value
  rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = COTradeList.Value
  rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = COItems.Value
  rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow, 4).Value = CODescription1.Value
  rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow, 5).Value = COPrice1.Value
  rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow, 6).Value = CODateIssued.Value
End With
```

Let's look at what you're doing here by breaking down a couple of the lines:

Firstly, your `With/End With` are irrelevant, you're not using WS3 at all here. They can go. They don't do any harm because they don't do anything. Everything inside this wrapper refers to everything in relation to `rng` anyway.

More importantly though, you're writing to cells using `rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow, X)`

So you refer to the table's range (called `rng`), **then you go to it's `.Parent`** which will be the sheet that `Table2` sits on *and then from cell A1* you find the cell using `LastRow` and x.

Now previously, `LastRow` examines the WS3 sheet to find the last cell/row used, not the `rng` or `Table2` - so you'll be writing to the row based on WS3, regardless of where `rng` sits.

If you can advise WHERE `Table1` and `Table2` are (which sheet, top left cell address) I think I might be able to update this but right now I'd be guessing.